# Abstract val instead of primary constructor argument

Tags: scala, scala-primary-constructor

Consider these two classes and the way the instances are created:

```
class Person1(val name: String)

val p1 = new Person1("John");
```

and:

```
abstract class Person2 {
  val name: String
}

val p2 = new Person2 {
  val name = "John"
}
```

Why would one prefer the latter (`Person2`) version? Every such a declaration causes new subclass to be created, also the code is slightly more verbose and less readable, however the second idiom is used throughout the *Programming in Scala* book several times. What are the advantages over straightforward field?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One simple use case is with traits, which cannot have constructor arguments.

Comment: Adding on what Jean said, you could have something like `trait HillBilly{ val name="Billy Bob" }` and create the Person like `val p2 = new Person2 with HillBilly`